# K-means clustering to identify warehouse location given factory location & demand points

Tags: python, k-means

I'm trying if a warehouse can help me improve my service level to my customers. If so, I want to identify where to establish the warehouse. I used the following logic in python to find the warehouse location.

> - Identified the lat, long and volume by district wise
> - Have run a k-means using volume as sample weight & identified optimum lat-long of the warehouse location

But, I'm confused how to incorporate the factory location in my analysis. Because even after establishing a warehouse, I will be servicing few closeby districts from the factory itself. Could you please suggest on how to go about this?

TIA

Comment: What is your logic to think that clustering is a good idea to find a location for your warehouse?

Comment: Isn't it? Clustering will minimize the distance(although not travel distance but I read that it is close enough). Also, clustering also adds weight to the volume. This will give me the ideal location for the warehouse.

Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

k-means is a classification algorithm. It serves to classify groups of things in sub groups, so you can treat the groups the same way.

For example, it may classify your clients in 3 groups, and when you inspect the groups, you may find that one group are families, other are males, other teens, other group small stores, and other group large companies.
But you do not input that info on the algorithm. You put data like amount of purchases, type of goods traded, time of day of sales, whatever.

Whether it serves or not, for your purpose, depends on the data you have.

From the little info you give, it looks like you have something closer to a transport problem, where the important data is the distance and time spent transporting things.
Probably TSP algorithms are more appropriate for tour problem.

Comment: Thanks Colim for the answer. I'm looking to solve the Facility location problem and to minimize the distance travelled. I realized clustering is not the right way to solve the problem but is there any better way to solve this in Python.

Comment: Isn't the k-means solving for minimum distance? Since, that is my most important metric I believe k-means isn't a bad approach after all.

Comment: Here is a wikipedia page explaining what k-means do https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering